# Why can't i get the content of an html table <td>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code that somehow scrapes a certain site. The problem is I can't proceed because I can't view the content of a table especially its `<td>`. You can see when you `print(table)`, it only shows the opening and closing tags if `<table>` and doesn't include its content.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.scstac.org/pc.jsp'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', class_='table02')
print(table)
```

Comment: The table is filled in by JavaScript, it's not in the HTML source. Use Selenium WebDriver to emulate the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pull from the json response used to create the table:

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.scstac.org/earthquake/now.do'

payload = {
        'dayCount': '1',
        'type': 'home'}


jsonData = requests.post(url, params=payload).json()
df = json_normalize(jsonData['earthHistory'])
df = df.dropna(axis=1)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateStr'], unit = 'ms')
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
          dateStr     depth      dip         earthDateStr         earthId     earthStatus  earthquakeLevel earthquakePosImgPath      enEarthSendDate enEarthquakeInLand enEarthquakeInfoRevised enEarthquakePosImgPath        enMhtResPath enNum enPublisher               enReferencePlace     enSendDate enSended            enSourceArea enTsuinfoPath enTsunamiForecastsRevised enTsunamiLevel           enTsunamiType        enTxtResPath enWarterInfoRevised        enXmlResPath  feIndex    lat     lon magType                                  magType_magValues     rake         referencePlace   strike        type      upDateStr           timestamp
0   1585208284000   15000.0 -99999.9  2020/03/26 15:38:04  20200326233800   RELESED_ALARM              6.3   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2020/03/26 15:44:54              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  202003261538_1.mht  en_1         范婷婷          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1585208694000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  202003261538_1.txt               false  202003261538_1.xml      259   5.63  125.22       M  Mw(mB)_6.375949859619141,Mwp_6.11729621887207,... -99999.9                菲律宾棉兰老岛 -99999.9  earthquake  1585208560000 2020-03-26 07:38:04
1   1579424301000   81000.0 -99999.9  2020/01/19 16:58:21  20200120005800  RELEASED_ALARM              6.3   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2020/01/19 17:05:35              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  202001191658_1.mht  en_1         赵联大  MINAHASSA PENINSULA, SULAWESI  1579424735000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  202001191658_1.txt               false  202001191658_1.xml      265  -0.22  123.94       M  Mw(mB)_6.259114742279053,Mwp_6.299142837524414... -99999.9               印尼米纳哈沙半岛 -99999.9  earthquake  1579424524000 2020-01-19 08:58:21
2   1576361512000   15000.0 -99999.9  2019/12/15 06:11:52  20191215141100   RELESED_ALARM              6.8   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/12/15 06:19:35              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201912150611_1.mht  en_1         范婷婷          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1576361975000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201912150611_1.txt               false  201912150611_1.xml      259   6.83  125.40       M  Mw(mB)_7.00132417678833,Mwp_6.967108726501465,... -99999.9                菲律宾棉兰老岛 -99999.9  earthquake  1576361787000 2019-12-14 22:11:52
3   1573719461000   45000.0     48.0  2019/11/14 16:17:41  20191115001700   RELESED_ALARM              7.1   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/11/14 18:59:12              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201911141617_2.mht  en_2         王君成           NORTHERN MOLUCCA SEA  1573729152000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201911141617_2.txt               false  201911141617_2.xml      266   1.59  126.42       M  Mw(mB)_7.46810245513916,Mwp_7.501344680786133,...    107.0               印尼马鲁古海北部    219.0  earthquake  1573719694000 2019-11-14 08:17:41
4   1572455481000   15000.0 -99999.9  2019/10/31 01:11:21  20191031091100  RELEASED_ALARM              6.7   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/10/31 01:19:42              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201910310111_1.mht  en_1         孙立宁          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1572455982000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE  Tsunami Threat Message  201910310111_1.txt               false  201910310111_1.xml      259   6.93  125.28       M  Mw(mB)_6.769245624542236,Mwp_6.674487590789795... -99999.9                菲律宾棉兰老岛 -99999.9  earthquake  1572455820000 2019-10-30 17:11:21
5   1572282285000   15000.0 -99999.9  2019/10/29 01:04:45  20191029090400  REALESED_ALARM              6.8   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/10/29 01:10:54              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201910290104_1.mht  en_1         王宗辰          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1572282654000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201910290104_1.txt               false  201910290104_1.xml      259   6.97  125.21     Mwp  Mw(mB)_6.970869064331055,Mwp_6.800000190734863... -99999.9  Mindanao, Philippines -99999.9  earthquake  1572282575000 2019-10-28 17:04:45
6   1571197028000   15000.0 -99999.9  2019/10/16 11:37:08  20191016193700  REALESED_ALARM              6.5   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/10/16 11:44:14              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201910161137_1.mht  en_1         李宏伟          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1571197454000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201910161137_1.txt               false  201910161137_1.xml      259   6.83  125.14     Mwp  Mw(mB)_6.415266513824463,Mwp_6.5,mb_6.03484487... -99999.9  Mindanao, Philippines -99999.9  earthquake  1571197370000 2019-10-16 03:37:08
7   1562483319000   15000.0 -99999.9  2019/07/07 15:08:39  20190707230800  REALESED_ALARM              7.0   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/07/07 15:21:34              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201907071508_1.mht  en_1         侯京明           NORTHERN MOLUCCA SEA  1562484094000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE  Tsunami Threat Message  201907071508_1.txt               false  201907071508_1.xml      266   0.57  126.31     Mwp  Mw(mB)_7.122064590454102,Mwp_7.0,mb_6.67208051... -99999.9   Northern Molucca Sea -99999.9  earthquake  1562483750000 2019-07-07 07:08:39
8   1555895485000   15000.0 -99999.9  2019/04/22 09:11:25  20190422171100  REALESED_ALARM              6.2   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/04/22 09:21:15              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201904220911_1.mht  en_1          高义             LUZON, PHILIPPINES  1555896075000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE  Tsunami Threat Message  201904220911_1.txt               false  201904220911_1.xml      249  15.79  119.67     Mwp  Mw(mB)_5.8734540939331055,Mwp_6.19999980926513... -99999.9     Luzon, Philippines -99999.9  earthquake  1555895712000 2019-04-22 01:11:25
9   1553373452000   60000.0 -99999.9  2019/03/24 04:37:32  20190324123700  REALESED_ALARM              6.2   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/03/24 04:48:04              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201903240437_1.mht  en_1         徐志国           NORTHERN MOLUCCA SEA  1553374084000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201903240437_1.txt               false  201903240437_1.xml      266   1.85  126.53     Mwp  Mw(mB)_6.164680480957031,Mwp_6.199999809265137... -99999.9   Northern Molucca Sea -99999.9  earthquake  1553373932000 2019-03-23 20:37:32
10  1546766840000   10000.0 -99999.9  2019/01/06 17:27:20  20190107012700  REALESED_ALARM              6.9   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2019/01/06 17:34:36              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201901061727_1.mht  en_1         王宗辰           NORTHERN MOLUCCA SEA  1546767276000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201901061727_1.txt               false  201901061727_1.xml      266   2.26  126.77     Mwp  Mw(mB)_6.7626872062683105,Mwp_6.90000009536743... -99999.9   Northern Molucca Sea -99999.9  earthquake  1546767157000 2019-01-06 09:27:20
11  1502400505000  172000.0 -99999.9  2017/08/11 05:28:25  20170811132800  REALESED_ALARM              6.2   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2017/08/11 05:48:14              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201708110528_1.mht  en_1          原野             LUZON, PHILIPPINES  1502401694000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201708110528_1.txt               false  201708110528_1.xml      249  14.00  120.74       M          Mw_6.199999809265137,M_6.199999809265137, -99999.9                 菲律宾吕宋岛 -99999.9  earthquake  1502401094000 2017-08-10 21:28:25
12  1495213578000  530000.0 -99999.9  2017/05/20 01:06:18  20170520090600  REALESED_ALARM              6.0   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2017/05/20 01:15:04              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201705200106_1.mht  en_1          原野          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1495214104000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201705200106_1.txt               false  201705200106_1.xml      259   9.38  123.95       M                                      Mw_6.0,M_6.0, -99999.9                菲律宾棉兰老岛 -99999.9  earthquake  1495213827000 2017-05-19 17:06:18
13  1493382198000   35000.0 -99999.9  2017/04/28 20:23:18  20170429042300       NEW_ALARM              6.9   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2017/04/28 20:44:05              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201704282023_1.mht  en_1          原野          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1493383445000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201704282023_1.txt               false  201704282023_1.xml      259   5.45  125.17      Mw          Mw_6.900000095367432,M_6.880000114440918, -99999.9  Mindanao, Philippines -99999.9  earthquake  1493383329000 2017-04-28 12:23:18
14  1484000028000  627000.0 -99999.9  2017/01/10 06:13:48  20170110141300  REALESED_ALARM              7.3   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2017/01/10 06:27:13              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  201701100613_1.mht  en_1          原野                    CELEBES SEA  1484000833000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE     Tsunami Information  201701100613_1.txt               false  201701100613_1.xml      262   4.48  122.62       M          Mw_7.300000190734863,M_7.300000190734863, -99999.9           苏拉威西海(西里伯斯海) -99999.9  earthquake  1513739142000 2017-01-09 22:13:48
15   209031067000   33000.0     35.0  1976/08/16 16:11:07  19760817001100  REALESED_ALARM              7.9   Earthquake_Pos.jpg  2017/12/22 06:28:20              false                   false     Earthquake_Pos.jpg  197608161611_3.mht  en_3          原野          MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES  1513895300000     true  South China Sea source   tsuinfo.txt                     false           BLUE  Tsunami Threat Message  197608161611_3.txt               false  197608161611_3.xml      259   6.26  124.02       M          Mw_7.900000095367432,M_7.900000095367432,     92.0                菲律宾棉兰老岛    341.0  earthquake  1513893811000 1976-08-16 08:11:07
```

Comment: Nice. I find this method interesting. This one is a lot faster.

Comment: in fact, just realized now that the datetime is already there. no need to convert to datetime (the last line)

Answer (score 0):

The website you are scraping is a dynamic website. The url you provide only has the skeleton of the table in the html. Later with JQuery scripts the table rows and cells are populated.

I suggest you research scraping dynamic websites. Se this site, does calls with a session cookie to get the data. I think the easiest way is a [scraping browser setup](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251/) to retrieve the data.

Comment: This helps me. I was able to get the table with the help of selenium.